# pop up window to tell something, then return

Tags: powershell, error-handling, dialog

In my PowerShell script, I'm using try/catch to handle errors. What I'd like to do is when an error caught, a popup window will show up and tell the error msg, then if the use clicks the ok button on this window, the function will just return.

For achieving this, I make my script like this,

```
Try{...}
Catch{
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("ErrorMessage: " + $ErrorMessage , "Oops" , 4)
return}
```

But with the script above, the function just simply returns without the popup window showing.

What am I supposed to do to make the window show?

Comment: I just ran `try { throw 'rocks' } catch { [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('1 ' + $ErrorMessage, '2', 4); return}` and it worked for me in both powershell and powershell_ise.  I did have to run `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms` in powershell, first.

Comment: Your error probably is a [non-terminating error](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2013/06/09/an-introduction-to-error-handling-in-powershell/).

Comment: do $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop" to top of your script